Why is a Thread-Scoped Bean Injected Instead of a Default-Scoped Bean in Spring Boot?
I recently made a change to my Spring Boot project. I initially had a bean without a specific scope. Due to an implementation that uses threads and the occurrence of concurrency issues, I needed to create another bean identical to the previous one but with a thread scope using SimpleThreadScope. However, when I use the first bean in a service for batch processing, the second bean is mistakenly injected, even though the references indicate the first bean. To solve this problem, I cannot add qualifiers to the beans because the project is very large.
Below is the structure of my code.
app-config.xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="thread">
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="reportService" class="it.myproject.service.report.ReportService">
    <property name="exporter" ref="exporter" />
    <property name="writer" ref="writer" />
</bean>


<bean id="reportServiceAsync" class="it.myproject.service.report.ReportService" scope="thread">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    <property name="exporter" ref="exporter" />
    <property name="writer" ref="writer" />
</bean>



<bean id="myMagicBean" class="it.myproject.batch.MyMagicBean">
    <property name="reportService" ref="reportService" />
</bean>

I'm having trouble understanding why myMagicBean injects reportServiceAsync instead of reportService, as defined in my configuration.
How can I resolve this issue?
Can anyone explain why this is happening?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Not without seeing additional context like the classes etc. However making things thread-scoped seem the wrong solution and you should be fixing the ReportService instead (feels like using a canon to solve an issue that you shouldn't have in the first place).

Hello @M.Deinum , and thank you for your help. I cannot share additional code details due to company policy.
The main issue is with ReportService, which uses a private attribute to store a file path. It's designed for synchronous execution, so there are no issues when operations are sequential. However, problems arise when multiple threads access and modify the path attribute with different values simultaneously. I want each thread to have its own path value. Should I use ThreadLocal instead of managing the thread scope?
Thank you in advance!

Use a ThreadLocal or even better don't use shared state. Is that shared state really needed?

Hi @M.Deinum, thank you so much for your response! After analyzing the situation, I realized that the shared attributes weren't strictly necessary. Therefore, I decided to remove them, which resolved the issue. I really appreciate your help; you're the best!

Thanks to @M.Deinum's comment, I realized that the issue was in my ReportService, and that using thread scope was not appropriate. I resolved the problem by removing the shared attributes between the various methods.
